# Как удалить повторяющиеся и пустые строки из *.txt?

Tags: php

Имеется текстовый файл temp6.txt в котором следующая информация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удаление повторений и пустых строк таким образом

```
file_put_contents('temp6.txt', array_unique(file('temp6.txt'))); //если в temp6.txt строки повторяются - удалить
$trim = file_put_contents('temp6.txt', array_filter(file('temp6.txt'),'trim')); // если есть пустые строки - удалить
```

**Не работает:**

7 и 8 строка (см. рисунок) должны удалиться, как я понимаю, но они остаются. То есть, толку от `array_unique` и `array_filter` никакого. Точнее, я скорей всего неправильно использую функции.

Благодаря варианту Алексея Шиманского:

```
$txt = file_get_contents($file);
$txt = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/m',"\n", $txt)); 
file_put_contents($file, $txt);
```

удалось избавиться от пустых строк. Но вот строки повторяются! `array_unique` бесполезная вещь какая-то. =(

**Сопутствующий вопрос. А как отсортировать строки в порядке убывания первых 10 символов (чисел, например: 0000000504, 0000000503 и т.д.)? Я думаю, что лучше всю строку не рассматривать, т.к. там числа с текстом вперемешку. Но не пойму, как задать выборку, которая как бы и будет являться флагом.**

**ВСЕМ СПАСИБО! ВСЁ СДЕЛАЛА**

Comment: и как именно оно не работает?

Comment: 7 и 8 строка (см. рисунок) должны удалиться, как я понимаю, но они остаются. То есть, толку от array_unique и array_filter никакого. Точнее, я скорей всего неправильно использую функции.

Comment: `trim`, использованный как `callback` в `array_filter`, запись не уберет...

Comment: попробуйте поменять `array_filter(file('temp6.txt'),'trim'))` на `array_filter(file('temp6.txt'),function ($el) { return ((strlen($el))?1:0); }))`. Это должно убрать 8-ю строчку.... а вот насчет array_unique - это странно... вроде правильно выглядит все

Comment: @cyadvert простите, а `return strlen($el) > 0;` не прокатит?

Comment: @cyadvert  не получается что-то и даже, как Алексей пишет тоже.(

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно прокатит. Просто мой вариант не так страшен для новичков... :) однако, как оказалось, все равно не работает :)

Comment: @Юленька в таком случае нужно от вас следующее: вместо скрина файла ,выложите его содержимое кодом, как это сделано с `file_put_contents('temp6.txt....`, включить отображение всех ошибок в php `error_reporting(E_ALL);` и сказать появляются ли какие-то сообщения об ошибке? А также, конкретно что не работает? Одна из двух функций или обе? или что?

Comment: не работают, похоже, обе функции. Также почитайте доки к функции `file()` (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php). Там можно включить флаг, `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` который решит одну из Ваших проблем.

Comment: Юлия, если прошую задачу решили, а теперь появился новый вопрос — задавайте его как новый вопрос, тут редактировать не надо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет, я не решила. Меня попросили скинуть файлы, чтобы картина стала ясней. Я скинула, но все пропали.

Comment: Про сортировку задайте отдельный вопрос, так как ни кто и не знаэт что вы его спросили ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я сортировку сделала.) @E_p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что все же не работает только вторая функция, а первая работает.

Вторая, при всех попытках сделать `trim` с помощью `array_filter` типа 
`array_filter(file('temp6.txt'), function ($el) { return strlen($el) > 0; })` 
конечно может удалить пустые строки, но при это если это строка - последняя, то может возникнуть трудность, т.к. видимых символов может и нет, зато символы переноса на новую строку и возврат каретки (`\r\n`) присутствуют. Аналогично даже если использовать функцию `file()` с флагом `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`.

Поэтому удалить пустые строки можно попробовать регулярным выражением.

В итоге все будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$file = 'temp6.txt';

file_put_contents($file, array_unique(file($file)));

$txt = file_get_contents($file);
$txt = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/m',"\n", $txt)); 
file_put_contents($file, $txt);
```

Comment: В функции `file()` есть другой флаг `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, который убирает возврат каретки в конце строки. Так что если использовать оба указанных флага, то проблема пустых строк как в начале, так и в конце файла решится.

Comment: @cyadvert тогда если написать `file_put_contents('temp6.txt', array_unique(file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)));` получится файл в одну строку

Comment: Ну так можно ж `implode()`нуть... `file_put_contents('temp6.txt', implode("\r\n", array_unique(file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))));` :)

Comment: @cyadvert можно!) Напишите) Глядишь - автору понравится

Comment: @cyadvert вы не проверяли – `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` убирает только "\n", или и другие варианты типа "\r\n" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский file_put_contents($file, array_unique(file($file))); - повторяющиеся строки остаются.(((

Comment: @cyadvert file_put_contents('temp6.txt', implode("\r\n", array_unique(file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)))); - очень изящно, но, к сожалению, все строки удаляет из файла.

Answer (score 3):

Удаление повторов у вас прекрасно работает. А с последней строчкой «проблема» не в ней, а в символе новой строки в конце предпоследней строки – собственно, каждая строка с данными заканчивается символом новой строки.

[image: скрин]

Чтобы «пустой строки» не было, надо у последней строки с данным отрезать символ новой строки в конце.

Наиболее близко к исходному коду был бы такой вариант:

```
$data = array_map( 'trim', array_unique( file( 'temp6.txt')));
$data = array_filter( $data, 'notEmpty');
file_put_contents( 'temp6.txt', implode( "\n", $data));

function notEmpty( $line) {
    return !empty( $line);
}
```

В первой строке в массив `$data` мы получаем уникальные строки без символа конца строки в конце каждой и пробелов по краям если были, что вряд ли.

Во второй выкидываем из массива пустые строки с помощью вспомогательной функции `notEmpty()`, хотя вряд ли там есть действительно пустые строки.

В третьей записываем в файл результат – соединяем элементы массива символом новой строки. Так после последней строки этого символа не будет.

Ну и мы молодцы, т.к. теперь читаем и пишем файл только по одному разу.

Comment: После выполнения первой строки у меня повторений нет, но в файле следующее: 1 стр - пустая; 2 стр - текст; 3 стр - пустая ... (n-2) стр - текст; (n-1) и (n) -пустые строки; Далее вторая строка: всё, как и в первом пункте + весь массив строк дублируется; после выполнения 3-ей строки - все строки в txt удаляются.))

Comment: Было бы здорово, если кусок "рабочего" файла вы расшарили, как есть – с оригинальными переносами строк.

Comment: А сюда файлы можно выкладывать? Удаление повторов у меня действительно работает. Но фишка вот в чем... на простом примере показываю. Имеется 1 2 3 4 5 3 и почему-то запись в temp6.txt произойдет следующим образом: 12453 (и тут же без пробелов) 12345 То есть, 2 раза с разными позициями строк. Это специфика работы `array_unique` или `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Можно ссылку на pastebin.com, как вариант. Два «комплекта» скорее всего появляются после двух записей в файл. Ещё подводный камень – разделители строк и ф-я `file()`. На Windows и (Mac,Linux) они разные. И лог-файл созданный на Linux прочитать на Windows ф-ей file() не получится. Может, из-за этого вылетает вся эта косячная магия? Лучше читать файл `file_get_contents()` и бить в массив регулярным выражением: `$data = array_map( 'trim', array_unique( mb_split( '/[\r\n]+/', 'temp6.txt')));`

Comment: ссылка на диск https://yadi.sk/d/-UpKLfw9noJiX Я положила туда папку с файлами + readme.txt где подробно описала, что есть и что получается

Comment: кстати, если я использую file_get_contents() то строки многократно повторяются и повторяются при обновление страницы (содержимое текстового файла temp6.txt выводится на страницу сайта).

Comment: Может это из-за некорректной записи строк в файл temp6.txt? @Sergiks

Answer (score 2):

1) Если версия ПХП позволяет (> 5.5) используй генераторы, что бы читать файл. Процесс использут меньше памяти, так как файл не надо хранить.

2) Использовать кэш для записанных строк. В примере МД5(что бы сохранить память).

3) Писать в другой файл. Зачем рисковать исходником?

```
<?php

function getLines($fileName) {
    if (!$fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'r')) {
        return;
    }

    while (false !== $line = fgets($fileHandle)) {
        yield $line;
    }

    fclose($fileHandle);
}

$cache = [];
$fh = fopen('file_to_write.txt', 'w');

foreach (getLines("test.txt") as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line == '') {
        continue;
    }

    $hash = md5($line);
    // EDIT 2: Более быстрый вариант. Еще меньше памяти.
    // $hash = crc32($line);
    if (!in_array($hash, $cache)) {
        // EDIT 1: As per comment
        fwrite($fh, $line . PHP_EOL);
        $cache[] = $hash;
    }
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: У меня получился файл в одну строку)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не показатель. Запустите на файле в 10Мб+ и померяйте память.

Comment: Не показатель чего, простите? Я полагаю конечный файл должен быть в несколько строк. Только без дублей и "пустышек". Говорю об этом недочете. Причем тут память вообще? Мне плевать хоть вообще не тратит память

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Рамки проблемы на самом деле не известны. (Какие файлы(размер), как часто надо конвертировать, на какой машине конвертируют(ОС, Память, Процессор), почему конвертируем, какая еще работа выполняется скриптом).
На данном сайте часто возникают вопросы типа "Че у меня память закончилась после того как я туда дофига впихнул". 
Поэтому решение сжатое в одну строку не обязательно будет оптимальным. Будь мой код на 100+ строк с ненужным ООП тогда да. А так байты нет смысла экономить.

Comment: Виноват trim($line), или смените проверку, связанную с пустой строкой или попробуйте изменить инструкцию записи так: fwrite($fh, $line."\n");

Comment: @АлексейШиманский На коментарий "у меня код меньше" я дал развернытый ответ почему это не важно. Что вас смутило?

Comment: @АлексейПрисяжный Спасибо, тестировал быстро не заметил.

Comment: @E_p Вы невнимательны и как-то не так интерпретировали мои слова. Я **НЕ** говорил, что "у меня код меньше".  Я написал, что "файл должен быть в несколько строк". Тот самый, выходной, который вы формируете. О чем повторно вам написал `Алексей Присяжный`. Вот о какой неточности я говорил. А какой у вас длины......мне абсолютно всё равно) я длиной кода не мерюсь))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Виноват не правильно понял.

Comment: Тоже сначала подумал про построчную обработку и коллекцию хэшей! md5 здесь уместен, т.к. сами строки длиннее 32 символов, т.е. будет выигрышь по сравнению с хранением всего массива в памяти. Вычисление хэша занимает какое-то время – это минус.

Comment: @Sergiks Согласен. Все от ситуации зависит. Как вариант можно проще чем мд5 алгоритм попробовать здесь не важно. crc32 например.